# find country from full domain name

Tags: python, dns

I am writing an script to analyse the countries of a list of domain names(e.g. `third.second.first`). The data set is pretty old and many of the fully qualified domain names cannot be found via `socket.gethostbyname(domain_str)` in python. Here are some of the alternatives I come up with:

1. Retrieving the ip of `second.first` if the ip of `third.second.first`
   cannot be found and then find the country of that ip

   - This seems not to be a good idea since a dns A-record can map a subdomain to an ip different from its primary domain.
2. detect the country code of the domain name. e.g. if it is *.*.jp, it is from Japan

My questions are:

- Is the first method acceptable ?
- are there other methods to retrieve the country information of a domain name ?

Thank you.

Comment: Download a load of data from Wikipedia and hard code it into a dictionary? Seems like the easiest way.

Comment: @TomWyllie may I know where that data is ?

Comment: [List of Internet top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the `geolite2` module:

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/maxminddb-geolite2

So you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
from geolite2 import geolite2

def origin(ip, domain_str, result):
    print("{0} [{1}]: {2}".format(domain_str.strip(), ip, result))

def getip(domain_str):
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain_str.strip())
    reader = geolite2.reader()      
    output = reader.get(ip)
    result = output['country']['iso_code']
    origin(ip, domain_str, result)

with open("/path/to/hostnames.txt", "r") as ins:
    for domain_str in ins:
        try:
            getip(domain_str)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("{0} [could not resolve]".format(domain_str.strip())) 
            if len(domain_str) > 2:
                subdomain = domain_str.split('.', 1)[1]
                try:
                    getip(subdomain)
                except:
                    continue

geolite2.close()
```

**Output:**

```
bing.com [204.79.197.200]: US
dd15-028.compuserve.com [could not resolve]
compuserve.com [149.174.98.149]: US
google.com [172.217.11.78]: US
```

Comment: I have tried this code on my dataset, but because it's in the millions, despite it working, it's veeeery slow. Is there any change that can be made to speed it up?